# Ubuntu 19.10 tweaks - desktop icons still not shown

Tags: 19.10, desktop-icons

I changed in tweaks to show desktop icons (Personal and trash) but on the desktop nothing happens.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are your extensions up-to-date? Visit https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and go to the **Installed Extensions** tab to check.

Comment: Try moving the open windows, or go to another workspace, so the desktop is visible ...

Comment: The desktop is empty, no trash or  personal folder on desktop.

Comment: Any Ideas on why after adding on tweaks trash and home folder to desktop they are missing from the desktop?